# Grafana Setup with Azure File as Storage

Tags: sqlite, grafana, go-sqlite3

[image]

What happened:
After creating and starting a container group with one container, grafana/grafana:6.4.4, the container shuts down and goes into a reboot loop. I mounted one volume via Azure File Share to /var/lib/grafana
What you expected to happen:
I expected the container to start and stay running, with the database created to the mounted volume.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: grafana
  name: grafana
  namespace: devops
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        supplementalGroups:
          - 0
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image: grafana/grafana:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: http-grafana
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /login
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3000
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 750Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
              name: grafana-pv
      volumes:
        - name: grafana-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: grafana-pvc
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

Mount option i am using are below;

```
 mountOptions:
 - dir_mode=0777
 - file_mode=0777
 - uid=1000
 - gid=1000
 - mfsymlinks
 - nobrl
 - cache=none
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by using the

https://blog.rishabkumar.com/grafana-on-azure-web-app-containers#heading-initiate-an-empty-sqlite-database

these configuration